# Place object within a layer in Python - Maya

Tags: python, button, layer, maya

Forgive me, i'm not incredibly good at Python, so please try and go easy on me.
I've got a basic program going that creates NURBS circles for Control Shapes on rigs in Maya, and i'm separating each area (Head, torso etc) into different layers.
Firstly, how do I change the layer colour. Watching the script editor, this should work but it doesn't. Probably just a syntax error of a noob:
cmds.createDisplayLayer (name = 'Head_Control_Shapes', cmds.setAttr ('Head_Control_Shapes').color=4)

My main question though is once this is created (This is run at Startup of the script), how do I place an object inside of it?
This is the code fragment that is relevant.
Thank you in advance

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
if cmds.window("RyanWindow", exists = True):
    cmds.deleteUI("RyanWindow")

myWindow = cmds.window(t="Ryan Window",w = 300, h = 300)
form = cmds.formLayout()

cmds.createDisplayLayer (name = 'Head_Control_Shapes', cmds.setAttr ('Head_Control_Shapes').color=4)
cmds.createDisplayLayer (name = 'Torso_Control_Shapes', cmds.setAttr ('Torso_Control_Shapes').color=12)
cmds.createDisplayLayer (name = 'Arms_Control_Shapes', cmds.setAttr ('Arms_Control_Shapes').color=13)
cmds.createDisplayLayer (name = 'Legs_Control_Shapes', cmds.setAttr ('Legs_Control_Shapes').color=31)
cmds.createDisplayLayer (name = 'Other_Control_Shapes', cmds.setAttr ('Other_Control_Shapes').color=2)


cmds.columnLayout(adj = True)
cmds.text("                         Custom Control Shape Creator v1                         ")
cmds.separator(height = 15, style='double' )
cmds.separator(height = 15, style='double' )
cmds.setParent( '..' )

tabs = cmds.tabLayout(innerMarginWidth=5, innerMarginHeight=5)
cmds.formLayout( form, edit=True, attachForm=((tabs, 'top', 40), (tabs, 'left', 0), (tabs, 'bottom', 0), (tabs, 'right', 0)) )

tab1 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=3)
cmds.button(label='Circle', command = "makeCircle()")
def makeCircle():
cmds.circle( nr=(0, 90, 1), c=(0, 0, 0) )
cmds.button(label='Square', command = "makeSquare()")
def makeSquare():
cmds.circle( nr=(0, 90, 1), c=(0, 0, 0) )
cmds.button(label='Oval')
cmds.setParent( '..' )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I refactored your code very slightly to make it work: (I will include some pointers below the code)

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
if cmds.window("RyanWindow", exists=True):
    cmds.deleteUI("RyanWindow")

myWindow = cmds.window(t="Ryan Window", w=300, h=300)
form = cmds.formLayout()

print cmds.createDisplayLayer (name='Head_Control_Shapes', empty=True)
cmds.createDisplayLayer (name='Torso_Control_Shapes', empty=True)
cmds.createDisplayLayer (name='Arms_Control_Shapes', empty=True)
cmds.createDisplayLayer (name='Legs_Control_Shapes', empty=True)
cmds.createDisplayLayer (name='Other_Control_Shapes', empty=True)

cmds.setAttr ('Head_Control_Shapes.color', 4)
cmds.setAttr ('Torso_Control_Shapes.color', 12)
cmds.setAttr ('Arms_Control_Shapes.color', 13)
cmds.setAttr ('Legs_Control_Shapes.color', 31)
cmds.setAttr ('Other_Control_Shapes.color', 2)

cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)
cmds.text("                         Custom Control Shape Creator v1                         ")
cmds.separator(height = 15, style='double' )
cmds.separator(height = 15, style='double' )
cmds.setParent( '..' )

tabs = cmds.tabLayout(innerMarginWidth=5, innerMarginHeight=5)
cmds.formLayout( form, edit=True, attachForm=((tabs, 'top', 40), (tabs, 'left', 0), (tabs, 'bottom', 0), (tabs, 'right', 0)) )

tab1 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=3)
cmds.button(label='Circle', command="makeCircle()")
cmds.button(label='Square', command="makeSquare()")
cmds.button(label='Oval')
cmds.setParent( '..' )


def makeCircle():
    cmds.circle( nr=(0, 90, 1), c=(0, 0, 0) )


def makeSquare():
    cmds.circle( nr=(0, 90, 1), c=(0, 0, 0) )


cmds.showWindow(myWindow)
```

The way you were using cmds.setAttr was wrong. `setAttr` shouldn't be part of the `cmds.createDisplayLayers` call. It is a separate command. That is why I split those two up like so:

```
cmds.createDisplayLayer (name='Torso_Control_Shapes', empty=True)
cmds.setAttr ('Head_Control_Shapes.color', 4)
```

The `empty=True` flag should be set. Otherwise, any objects possibly selected prior to running the script will be added to the newly created layer.

To add an object to a layer DURING CREATION of the layer, you can just pre-select the object(s) and create the layer using `cmds.createDisplayLayers` without setting the `empty` flag. If you set the `noRecurse=True` flag, only the object selected will be added, otherwise all it's decendants, you would also be added.

To add an object AFTER creation of the layer you would use the `editDisplayLayerMembers` method. You would do this like:

```
cmds.editDisplayLayerMembers('Torso_Control_Shapes', object1, object2)
# where object1 and object2 are strings containing the names of your objects
```

Note: I also removed spacing around the '=' symbol in your method calls. [Pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends not having these in parameter assignment in method calls.

Also do check out the docs for more examples and options:
http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/editDisplayLayerMembers.html
http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/createDisplayLayer.html

Comment: Cannot thank you enough, also, thanks for the annotations and advice. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

mySelection = cmds.ls(sl=True) # create selection variable

cmds.createDisplayLayer (name = "hidden_item", number = 1, empty=True) # create empty display layer

cmds.editDisplayLayerMembers( 'hidden_item', mySelection ) # store my selection into the display layer

cmds.setAttr("hidden_item.visibility", 0) # change an attr of the display layer